# how to join collections in faunadb?

Tags: faunadb

I want to get nested `ref`'s value within the query I'm executing, but by default response is returning the `ref` of other collection. consider this minimum example; here are `user` and `coin` models, within `"users"` and `"coins"` collections

```
user {     // ref: 123456
  name: foo
  location: bar
}
```

```
coin {     // ref: 124457
  amount: 5457
  awardedTo: Ref(Collection("users"), "123456")
}
```

when I run this query

```
q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection("coins"), "124457"))
```

the response is something like this:

```
{
  data: {
    amount: 5457,
    awardedTo: @ref: {id: "123456", collection: {…}}
  },
  ref: @ref: {id: "124457", collection: {…}},
  ts: 1622547855525255
}
```

But how is it possible to get nested `user`'s value in the same query to have a response like this:

```
{
  data: {
    amount: 5457,
    awardedTo: {
      name: foo,
      location: bar
    }
  },
  ref: @ref: {id: "124457", collection: {…}},
  ts: 1622547855525255
}
```

I have read [`Join`](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/join?lang=javascript)'s documentation but it wasn't helpful in this case, and also tried this way, but it didn't work either:

```
q.Let({
  coin: q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection("coins"), '124457'))
},
  q.Union(
    q.Get(q.Select(["data","awaredTo"], q.Var("coin"))),
    q.Var("coins")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this FQL:

```
Let(
  {
    coin: Select(['data'],Get(Ref(Collection("coin"), "1"))),
    user: Select(['data'],Get(Select(['awardedTo'],Var('coin'))))
  },
  Merge(Var('coin'),{awardedTo:Var('user')})
)
```

It retrieves data from coin, extracts the user ref and merge all together.

Luigi

Comment: I was expecting a "fancier" solution, using `Join` or something but this will do the trick.

Comment: by the way do you think this whole query would cost 2 read operations? since 2 `Select` for two collections, or 1 read operation for whole query

Comment: Hi Leonardo, is not Select() that actually read the documents, but Get(). In that case yes, you have to get 2 different documents, so 2 reads.