# How to get nested documents in FaunaDB with a filter?

Tags: faunadb

The following query:

```
  Paginate(Documents(Collection("backyard"))),
  Lambda(
    "f",
    Let(
      {
        backyard: Get(Var("f")),
        user: Get(Select(["data", "user"], Var("backyard")))
      },
      {
        backyard: Var("backyard"),
        user: Var("user")
      }
    )
  )
)
```

results to:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      backyard: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333719283470172352"),
        ts: 1654518359560000,
        data: {
          user: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
          product: "15358",
          date: "2022-06-06",
          counter: "1"
        }
      },
      user: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
        ts: 1654517707220000,
        data: {
          email: "<email>",
          name: "Paolo"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      backyard: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333747850716381384"),
        ts: 1654545603400000,
        data: {
          user: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
          product: "15358",
          date: "2022-06-08",
          counter: "4"
        }
      },
      user: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
        ts: 1654517707220000,
        data: {
          email: "<email>",
          name: "Paolo"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter backyard by date without losing the nested users?

I tried:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Range(Match(Index("backyard_by_date")), "2022-05-08", "2022-06-08")),
  Lambda(
    "f",
    Let(
      {
        backyard: Get(Var("f")),
        user: Get(Select(["data", "user"], Var("backyard")))
      },
      {
        backyard: Var("backyard"),
        user: Var("user")
      }
    )
  )
)
```

However, the resultset is an empty array and the following already returns an empty array:

```
Paginate(Range(Match(Index("backyard_by_date")), "2022-05-08", "2022-06-08"))
```

My index:

```
{
  name: "backyard_by_date",
  unique: false,
  serialized: true,
  source: "backyard"
}
```

Maybe I have to adjust my index? The following helped me a lot:

- [How to get nested documents in FaunaDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104940/how-to-get-nested-documents-in-faunadb)
- [How to Get Data from two collection in faunadb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624307/how-to-get-data-from-two-collection-in-faunadb)
- [how to join collections in faunadb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007378/how-to-join-collections-in-faunadb)

Comment: Can you update your question to include the definition of the "backyard_by_date" index?

Comment: @eskwayrd: I updated the question and added the index definition.

Comment: That index definition has no `terms` specified. If that's what you're actually using, that's the problem. An index with no `terms` or `values` is called a "collection index": all of a collection's documents are included, with no matching `terms` to subset the group, and the default result includes document references, which cannot be used for date comparisons.

Perhaps ask your question in the Fauna Forums, which is more conducive to a conversation that eventually arrives at solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your index definition is missing details. Once that gets fixed, everything else you were doing is exactly right.

In your provided index, there are no `terms` or `values` specified, which makes the `backyard_by_date` index a "collection" index: it only records the references of every document in the collection. In this way, it is functionally equivalent to using the `Documents` function but incurs additional write operations as documents are created or updated within the `backyard` collection.

To make your query work, you should delete your existing index and (after 60 seconds) redefine it like this:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "backyard_by_date",
  source: Collection("backyard"),
  values: [
    {field: ["data", "date"]},
    {field: ["ref"]}
  ]
})
```

That definition configures the index to return the `date` field and the reference for every document.

Let's confirm that the index returns what we expect:

```
> Paginate(Match(Index("backyard_by_date")))
{
  data: [
    [ '2022-06-06', Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333719283470172352") ],
    [ '2022-06-08', Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333747850716381384") ]
  ]
}
```

Placing the `date` field's value first means that we can use it effectively in `Range`:

```
> Paginate(Range(Match(Index("backyard_by_date")), "2022-05-08", "2022-06-08"))
{
  data: [
    [ '2022-06-06', Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333719283470172352") ],
    [ '2022-06-08', Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333747850716381384") ]
  ]
}
```

And to verify that `Range` is working as expected:

```
> Paginate(Range(Match(Index("backyard_by_date")), "2022-06-07", "2022-06-08"))
{
  data: [
    [ '2022-06-08', Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333747850716381384") ]
  ]
}
```

Now that we know the index is working correctly, your filter query needs a few adjustments:

```
> Map(
  Paginate(
    Range(Match(Index("backyard_by_date")), "2022-05-08", "2022-06-08")
  ),
  Lambda(
    ["date", "ref"],
    Let(
      {
        backyard: Get(Var("ref")),
        user: Get(Select(["data", "user"], Var("backyard")))
      },
      {
        backyard: Var("backyard"),
        user: Var("user")
      }
    )
  )
)
{
  data: [
    {
      backyard: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333719283470172352"),
        ts: 1657918078190000,
        data: {
          user: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
          product: '15358',
          date: '2022-06-06',
          counter: '1'
        }
      },
      user: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
        ts: 1657918123870000,
        data: { name: 'Paolo', email: '<email>' }
      }
    },
    {
      backyard: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("backyard"), "333747850716381384"),
        ts: 1657918172850000,
        data: {
          user: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
          product: '15358',
          date: '2022-06-08',
          counter: '4'
        }
      },
      user: {
        ref: Ref(Collection("user"), "333718599460978887"),
        ts: 1657918123870000,
        data: { name: 'Paolo', email: '<email>' }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the index returns a date string and a reference, the `Lambda` inside the `Map` has to accept those values as arguments. Aside from renaming `f` to `ref`, the rest of your query is unchanged.